# ASP.NET web handler run command as requesting user

Tags: asp.net

From a web handler (xxx.ashx) I need to run a command as the same user using the web page and sending the request.  I have IIS setup using impersonation, have code in my .ashx that shows it is impersonating the user, and then I use the C# Process.start() to run the command.  (It's a .cmd file I am running)

The problem is that the .cmd file runs as the user assigned to the Application Pool and not the web user.  I even tried this code:

WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext = ((WindowsIdentity)System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()).Impersonate();

Could this be an issue:  I wrote the .ashx file and put just it under the IIS wwwroot/myapp folder and call it from a URL from a web browser.  I have setup the Application Pool using the DefaultAppPool user and an OS user, but no difference.

I'm a novice with IIS & ASP too so this is like working in a black box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had to use the native windows method: CreateProcessAsUser(), and had to call DuplicateTokenEx() to duplicate the security token.

```
    <%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="batchRunSAS" %>
    using System;

    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Security.Principal;

    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Security;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.ComponentModel;

            public class batchRun : IHttpHandler
    {
        public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context)
        {
            //Call DuplicateTokenEx
            //https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682429(VS.85).aspx
            //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095909/createprocessasuser-creating-window-in-active-session
            Process process = null;

            process = NativeMethods.CreateProcessAsUser("C:\\temp\\test.exe");
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
        class NativeMethods
        {
            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
            public struct STARTUPINFO
            {
                public Int32 cb;
                public string lpReserved;
                public string lpDesktop;
                public string lpTitle;
                public Int32 dwX;
                public Int32 dwY;
                public Int32 dwXSize;
                public Int32 dwXCountChars;
                public Int32 dwYCountChars;
                public Int32 dwFillAttribute;
                public Int32 dwFlags;
                public Int16 wShowWindow;
                public Int16 cbReserved2;
                public IntPtr lpReserved2;
                public IntPtr hStdInput;
                public IntPtr hStdOutput;
                public IntPtr hStdError;
            }

            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
            public struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
            {
                public IntPtr hProcess;
                public IntPtr hThread;
                public Int32 dwProcessID;
                public Int32 dwThreadID;
            }

            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
            public struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
            {
                public Int32 Length;
                public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
                public bool bInheritHandle;
            }

            public enum SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL
            {
                SecurityAnonymous,
                SecurityIdentification,
                SecurityImpersonation,
                SecurityDelegation
            }

            public enum TOKEN_TYPE
            {
                TokenPrimary = 1,
                TokenImpersonation
            }

            public const int GENERIC_ALL_ACCESS = 0x10000000;
            public const int CREATE_NO_WINDOW = 0x08000000;

            [
               DllImport("kernel32.dll",
                  EntryPoint = "CloseHandle", SetLastError = true,
                  CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)
            ]
            public static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

            [
               DllImport("advapi32.dll",
                  EntryPoint = "CreateProcessAsUser", SetLastError = true,
                  CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)
            ]
            public static extern bool
               CreateProcessAsUser(IntPtr hToken, string lpApplicationName, string lpCommandLine,
                                   ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes, ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,
                                   bool bInheritHandle, Int32 dwCreationFlags, IntPtr lpEnvrionment,
                                   string lpCurrentDirectory, ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo,
                                   ref PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);

            [
               DllImport("advapi32.dll",
                  EntryPoint = "DuplicateTokenEx")
            ]
            public static extern bool
               DuplicateTokenEx(IntPtr hExistingToken, Int32 dwDesiredAccess,
                                ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,
                                Int32 ImpersonationLevel, Int32 dwTokenType,
                                ref IntPtr phNewToken);

            public static Process CreateProcessAsUser(string filename, string args)
            {
                var hToken = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Token;
                var hDupedToken = IntPtr.Zero;

                var pi = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();
                var sa = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
                sa.Length = Marshal.SizeOf(sa);

                try
                {
                    if (!DuplicateTokenEx(
                            hToken,
                            GENERIC_ALL_ACCESS,
                            ref sa,
                            (int)SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL.SecurityIdentification,
                            (int)TOKEN_TYPE.TokenPrimary,
                            ref hDupedToken
                        ))
                        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

                    var si = new STARTUPINFO();
                    si.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(si);
                    si.lpDesktop = "";

                    var path = Path.GetFullPath(filename);
                    var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);

                    // Revert to self to create the entire process; not doing this might
                    // require that the currently impersonated user has "Replace a process
                    // level token" rights - we only want our service account to need
                    // that right.
                    using (var ctx = WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(IntPtr.Zero))
                    {
                        if (!CreateProcessAsUser(
                                                hDupedToken,
                                                path,
                                                string.Format("\"{0}\" {1}", filename.Replace("\"", "\"\""), args),
                                                ref sa, ref sa,
                                                false, 0, IntPtr.Zero,
                                                dir, ref si, ref pi
                                        ))
                            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                    }

                    return Process.GetProcessById(pi.dwProcessID);
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (pi.hProcess != IntPtr.Zero)
                        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
                    if (pi.hThread != IntPtr.Zero)
                        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
                    if (hDupedToken != IntPtr.Zero)
                        CloseHandle(hDupedToken);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```